# Hide DataTable while loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I am using jquery DataTable v 1.10.11 .. i want to hide the whole table and the div in which it is displayed while the datatable is loading data from the server via ajax call.. I searched but found suggestions to initialize the table in the success of the ajax call which i cannot do as i am performing many tasks on the same table like add/edit/delete. below is my dataTable declaration .

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//some code ....

var listTable = $('#listTable').DataTable({
                'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
                $(nRow).attr('id', 'my' + iDataIndex);
                $(nRow).attr('name', 'my' + iDataIndex); // or whatever you choose to set as the id
                },
                "tableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "aButtons": [
                            {
                                "sExtends": "copy",
                                "sButtonText": "Copy To ClipBoard",
                            },
                            {
                                "sExtends": "xls",
                                "sFileName": "*.xls",
                                "sButtonText": "Download XLS",
                            },
                            {
                                "sExtends": "print",
                            }                          
                     ]
                  },
                  "bInfo": false,
                  "sEmptyTable": "There are no records",
                  "processing": true,
                  "oLanguage": {
                        "sProcessing": "<img src='${request.contextPath}/images/ajax-loader.gif'>"
                },
                "dom": '<"toolbar">T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    });

    $('.dataTables_empty').html("");

//some more code 
//some url
listTable.ajax.url(url).load()

    });
```

Below is the table HTML code

```
<div id="data_table_travelHistory" style="margin:0 auto; padding-top:10px; width:90%;">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  id="listTable" style="width:100%;" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead class="alignCenter">
                 <tr>
          <th class="headerclass">Start Date</th>
          <th class="headerclass">Approval Status</th>
          <th class="headerclass">Created On</th>
          <th class="headerclass">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody></tbody>
              <tfoot  class="alignCenter headerclass">
                 <tr>
          <th class="headerclass">Start Date</th>
          <th class="headerclass">Approval Status</th>
          <th class="headerclass">Created On</th>
          <th class="headerclass">Action</th>
                 </tr>
              </tfoot>
              </table>
           </div>
```

Currently i am able to show a gif loading image while the DataTable is loading . But the initialized table always appears in the background which does not look good. Is there a way i can hide the whole DataTable and the div in which it is and only show the loading bar .... Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the table in ready event, then add remove a css class that shows/hide the table at the end of the ajax request.

Comment: The gif could be inside the same container and you can use the same method to show/hide the gif.